# reading click event name getting wired outputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, highcharts

I am trying to read a clicked series name of one my Bar from Highcharts Bar Chart and send this to some other page for further use.

What i was doing so far for example.

in first.jsp click event

```
$('#someid').val(this.series.name);
```

in Second.jsp

```
<form:hidden id="someid" htmlEscape="true">
```

and then i use the series anywhere in jsp for several condition verifications

if($('#someid').val() === "eventname"){}else{} // I use this 10 times in this page for conditions

this is functioning well until now but failing in HTMLUNIT tests.

Now i Changed in Second.jsp for more convenient

```
var seriesName = $('#someid').val();
if(seriesName === "eventname"){}else{}  //Here i always getting seriesname as empty.
```

and thus both functional and HTMUNIT tests are failing. Can any one tell me where i might have gone wrong or best way to read this and keep in for even Tests..

Thanks.

Comment: firstly, I have no clue about jsp ... what html element does a `<form:hidden` result in? if it isn't an input element, it wont have a value

Comment: You can catch series click event: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.events.click, but Im not sure how this is mapped in jsp

Comment: I just mapped the series name to hidden variable i.e. client side.